# Unable to cp a folder

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I am trying to use Terminal to copy lets say file3 and then (renaming is to file) from `~/file1/file2/file3`to `file1` but every time I try to do it, it fails.

My command is

```
cp -r ~/file1 /file2/file3  /../../file
```

I am getting error saying :

```
cp: ../../file: Permission denied
cp: file1/file2/file3: unable to copy extended attributes to ../../file: Permission denied
```

Can someone tell me how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to navigate upwards from the file system root when defining the target as `/../../file`. Have you tried using the absolute path for the target file?